# Bash glob in string comparison

Tags: bash, if-statement

The other day I was struggling with an if statement. Turns our my variable had a white space at the beginning. So I tried to conquer this with the following code but I am having no luck.

```
if [ "$COMMAND_WAIT" == "*REBOOT" ]; then
sudo /etc/kca/scripts/reboot.sh
echo "REBOOTING"
fi
```

Should I be able to wildcard this statement or is there another way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work. It uses `[[` instead of `[`, and no quotes around the *pattern*.

```
if [[ "$COMMAND_WAIT" == *REBOOT ]]; then
    sudo /etc/kca/scripts/reboot.sh
    echo "REBOOTING"
fi
```

`[[ expression ]]` is a compound expression, with special rules regarding expansions and quoting. In contrast, `[` is a builtin command, i.e. `*REBOOT` will be expanded as a pathname. In most cases, it's easier to use `[[` instead of `[`.

Comment: Thats Superb, Works perfectly whats  the difference in using [[ ~ ]]